# How to remove all characters after a certain character using Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, replace

I need to know how we can remove all the characters in a string after a certain characters using Python 3.

For example for the string `abcd (Read the tnc below!)` I need only `abcd`. I want to remove all what we have in the `()`.

I can use this Python code for now:

```
mystr = "abcd (Read the tnc below!)"

char = ""

for c in mystr:
    if c != "(":
        char += c
    else:
        break
```

But that seems to me to be the long and bad code for doing such a simple task. I tried searching online too, but didn't find any help. Does Python 3 have some great regex for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`

```
>>> mystr = "abcd (Read the tnc below!)"
>>>
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\(.*', '', mystr)
'abcd '
```

To remove everything between parenthesis

```
>>> mystr = "abcd (Read the tnc below!)"
>>> re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', mystr)
'abcd '
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
mystr.split("(")[0]
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks so much. My code is just a demo of what we can do. Even this goes in that category. What I wanted to ask for is does it have a regex so that I only remove characters in the () and not outside of it? Thanks again!

Comment: @CoderAmogh the answer is the solution of your question... maybe you should improve your question to this feature that you need

Comment: Request you to please read again. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would also use the `split` solution above, but if you're looking for a regex, it's as simple as `^(.*?)\(` - this will match until the first open bracket

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I need to delete only inside the () and not outside of it...